# Update concat text with null value in mysql

Tags: mysql

trasaction table description field have some value it is worked fine.
description feild default value is NULL,its not works..

```
update transaction set domain='hiox.com',description=CONACT(description,',domain swapped from hioxindia.com to hiox.com') where id=23602
```

help me..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `ifnull()`:

```
update `transaction` 
   set domain='hiox.com',
   description=CONCAT(ifnull(description, ''), ',domain swapped from hioxindia.com to hiox.com') 
where id=23602
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)